# Resize image using canvas in jquery before upload increase file size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, image-resizing

I am using `canvas` for resize image upload by user.

Resolution of Image I upload is 4000x3000 and its size is 962 kb
After resize image becomes 2000x1500 but its size increases to 2.1MB

Before resize
[image]

After resize its become 2.1 MB

Resize code is:

```
fileReader.onload = function (event) {
var image = new Image();

image.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("original-Img").src=image.src;
  var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
  var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width=image.width/2;
  canvas.height=image.height/2;
  context.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  document.getElementById("upload-Preview").src =  canvas.toDataURL();
  }
   image.src=event.target.result;
};
```

Why the file size of image increases?

Comment: How do you check the size? because `canvas.toDataURL()` returns a bas64 string and that is bigger than a binary representation of the image

Comment: With that much difference in size, it's probably because the original image was a JPEG, which uses a highly compressed format for encoding the data. **Edit** Yep, checking the link, it is indeed a JPEG. Use the [optional arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to select JPEG output instead of PNG which is the default, but note that a base64 string is going to be 4/3 the actual size of the raw image data.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you mean canvas resize not works on jpeg?

Comment: My statement was very clear. Your original image is a JPEG. Your output image is a PNG. [_**read the documentation**_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) and figure out how to output a JPEG instead.